# Replace if missing (.) (Stata)

Tags: stata

My data looks as below:

```
dataex pchange
-20
.
3
-47
44
.
0
```

And I wrote the following code:

```
gen ind_inc=""
replace ind_inc="Decreased" if pchange<0
replace ind_inc="Same" if pchange==0
replace ind_inc="Increased" if pchange>1
```

The first three lines work as intended, however, in rows where pchange is missing ".", they are classified as Increased under the ind_inc variable, how can I correct that?

```
pchange    labor_inc
-50         Decreased
.           Increased
.             Increased
-44        Decreased
0         Same
```

Comment: Why >1 rather than >0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing values in Stata are treated as very large positive values. See `help missing` for more info.

In your case, you've written `replace ind_inc="Increased" if pchange>1`. When `pchange` is missing, it is a very large positive value, which is greater than one so `ind_inc` is replaced.

Instead, you can use the following:

`replace ind_inc="Increased" if pchange>1 & !missing(pchange)`

Comment: It makes sense to compute % change as ```gen pchange =.
gen pchange = (pr8-pr7)/pr7*100``` If pr8 is the new period and pr7 is the old period, correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense. Also see the comment above about >1 vs. >0 by @NickCox as that is important too.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than another answer, but will be easier to read shown this way. Even with an obvious fix to

```
gen ind_inc=""
replace ind_inc="Decreased" if pchange<0
replace ind_inc="Same" if pchange==0
replace ind_inc="Increased" if pchange>0
```

this is a bad idea, as you will find as soon as you try to tabulate or graph results. `ind_inc` remembers nothing about its origin, so will display in alphabetical order, `"Decreased" "Increased" "Same"`. It's hard to believe that that is what you want.

I recommend something more like

```
gen ind_inc = sign(pchange) if pchange < . 
label define ind_inc -1 "Decreased" 0 "Same" 1 "Increased" 
label val ind_inc ind_inc
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, this is better for visualization purposes.